# EXCEL: Link to Cell Content inside LINE()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula containing:

=INDIRECT("T1!O"&ROW(2:20000))

Now I would like to dynamically replace the 200000 with the number in another cell (let's say B10) in the same worksheet as the cell containing the formula.

I tried all versions of using a second "indirect" but found no way this might be working. 
I'm grateful for all kind of tips!

Comment: what language are you using?  I am not familiar with the ZEILE function

Comment: sorry, missed that one when translating. ZEILE is german for ROW. changed it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDIRECT(T1&"!O" & ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & A1)))
```

Change `A1` to the cell containing `20000`.

Comment: Nice nesting of the indirects!

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thanks!